# Detect whether the screen has been touched

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile app and the first page has a bunch of controls on it as well as blank areas.

I need to detect that the user has touched the screen, anywhere, and move to another page on touch.

Is there a way to do this naturally through jQuery Mobile or do I need to code it all in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for **tap** event. ::Triggers after a quick, complete touch event.
Ref: [jqueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)
Did you mean something like this.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks.  Have combined that with $.mobile.changePage and it looks great